# I am not able to set the imagick module in php

Tags: php, imagick

I have a problem installing imagick and loading modules from php, but I have not found the cause of any problems at all. What is the workaround for this problem?

**My environment**:

- Apache : v2.4.25
- XAMPP-OSX - v5.6.30-1
- PHP - v5.6.30
- macOSX Sierra - v10.12.5
- Homebrew - v1.3.1
- php56-imagick - v3.4.3_4
- imagemagick - v7.0.6-9

**Installation process**:

```
brew install imagemagick

brew search imagemagick

brew install php56-imagick —build-from-source

brew search php56-imagick
```

**My php.ini file:**

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56-imagick/3.4.3_4/imagick.so"
```

**My phpinfo:**

```
Loaded Configuration File - /Application/XAMPP?camppfiles/etc/php.in
```

**My error log **

```
[25-Aug-2017 12:40:55 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56-imagick/3.4.3_4/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56-imagick/3.4.3_4/imagick.so, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib

Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/imagemagick/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.3.dylib

Reason: Incompatible library version: libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.3.dylib requires version 21.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 15.0.0 in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Perhaps PHP - v5.6.30 is not compatible with Imagemagick 7. You could try a more current PHP (if it exists) or use IM 6. The error message implies that there is a conflict in version of libfreetype. Do you have more than one version on your system? Or perhaps you loaded the wrong version from Homebrew

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for your reply. So I need to install imagemagick @ 6 version or upgrade php version?

Comment: I am not an expert on deducing errors in Imagemagick and Imagick installs. So these are only suggestions to try. I would suggest you first look to see what conflict or versions you have installed for libfreetype (Freetype delegate) that Imagemagick needs. Perhaps Imagick has installed one version that is not compatible with Imagemagick or vice-versa.

Comment: @fmw42 Sorry for the late confirmation. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Did you fix your problem? If so, please tell us what was the issue and how you solved it.